# Solving Second order ODE with variable coefficients?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$m\ddot{x} + c(x)\dot{x} + k(x)x = 0$

where

$\dot{x} = \dfrac{dx}{dt}, \ddot{x} = \dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ and $k(x), c(x)$ are functions of $x$. I saw some methods to solve variable coefficient ODEs but they had functions of $t$ as coefficients rather than functions of $x$.

My question is what is the approach to solve the above ODE?

Comment: do you need an analytical solution, or a numerical one?

Comment: Taylor series or [Frobenius method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method), depending on singularities of $k(x)$ and $c(x)$.

Comment: @the_candyman, I'll prefer an analytical one as this equation is part of a control loop and thus has to solved again and again if it is a numerical solution. Right?

Comment: @Marc, But the Frobenius method seems to solve $u''+{p(z) \over z}u'+{q(z) \over z^2}u = 0$ this kind of equations. The functions are of $z$, not of $u$.

Comment: @SPRajopal, for control purposes, maybe more indicated to use a numerical integrator. It can be more efficient than substituting value at each time, since analytical solution can be a transcendent function

Comment: @the_candyman Alright, so how do I obtain the numerical solution?

Comment: @SPRajagopal do you use Matlab?

Comment: @the_candyman, Yes

Comment: @SPRajagopal have you ever used functions like ode45, or similar?

Comment: @the_candyman, yes, but I don't want to depend on solvers. The model goes into a atmega board. I'm not sure a solver can help there. Is there any other way I can solve this once and use that general solution for a certain domain?

Comment: @SPRajagopal you can try to implement an integrator on you hardware. Anyway, if you want a close form solution, try to post $c(x)$ and $k(x)$ in your question. Maybe someone can help you, but without $c(x)$ and $k(x)$ it's hard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an ODE on the autonomous kind.

Let $\frac{dx}{dt} = F(x)$

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = \frac{dF}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{dF}{dx}F(x)$$

$$ m\frac{dF}{dx}F(x) +c(x)F(x)+xk(x) =0$$

This non-linear first order ODE is a particular form of Abel's equations of the second kind. All cannot be analytically solved, depending on the kind of functions $c(x)$ and $k(x)$.

Comment: So could you direct me to a method which can be used to solve the final form of the equation above?

Comment: If such method was existing, one could solve all the Abel's equations. It is not the case as already said.

Comment: Alright, understood. Thank you.